# Installing wmic on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, server

Has anyone managed to get wmic installed onto Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Server?
These instructions worked on 14.04 (including for people on 14.04) but I'm hitting error after error on 16.04 and wondered if anyone else had success

```
cd /tmp
mkdir wmic
cd wmic

apt install autoconf gcc libdatetime-perl make build-essential g++ python-dev
wget http://www.opsview.com/sites/default/files/wmi-1.3.16.tar_.bz2
bunzip2 wmi-1.3.16.tar_.bz2
tar -xvf wmi-1.3.16.tar_
cd wmi-1.3.16/

vim Samba/source/pidl/pidl
:583 (to jump to line 583)
remove the word defined before @$pidl
:wq 

export ZENHOME=/usr
make "CPP=gcc -E -ffreestanding"
cp Samba/source/bin/wmic /bin
```

Many thanks

Comment: Can you link where you got the instructions from?

Comment: Is this the most complete article I've found, but I've used the newer source from opsview but under Ubuntu 16.04 I keep hitting buid errors http://www.edcint.co.nz/checkwmiplus/InstallationTerminalSession

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the interest of knowledge sharing here is how to get wmic working on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, the issue was the limit of the number of open files

```
ulimit -n 100000
cd /tmp
mkdir wmic
cd wmic

apt install autoconf gcc libdatetime-perl make build-essential g++ python-dev
wget http://www.opsview.com/sites/default/files/wmi-1.3.16.tar_.bz2
bunzip2 wmi-1.3.16.tar_.bz2
tar -xvf wmi-1.3.16.tar_
cd wmi-1.3.16/

vim Samba/source/pidl/pidl
:583 (to jump to line 583)
remove the word defined before @$pidl
:wq 

export ZENHOME=/usr
make "CPP=gcc -E -ffreestanding"
cp Samba/source/bin/wmic /bin
```

Should now be working.

Comment: added that to my blog: http://tm-experimental.blogspot.ru/2018/04/wmic-ubuntu.html

thank you

Answer (score 3):

followed the steps in trevrobwhite's answer and was stuck at this:

```
Linking bin/wmic
bin/static/libtls.a(tls.o): In function `tls_init_server':
/tmp/wmic/wmi-1.3.16/Samba/source/lib/tls/tls.c:508: undefined reference to `gnutls_transport_set_lowat'
bin/static/libtls.a(tls.o): In function `tls_init_client':
/tmp/wmic/wmi-1.3.16/Samba/source/lib/tls/tls.c:579: undefined reference to `gnutls_certificate_type_set_priority'
/tmp/wmic/wmi-1.3.16/Samba/source/lib/tls/tls.c:587: undefined reference to `gnutls_transport_set_lowat'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:9029: recipe for target 'bin/wmic' failed
make[1]: *** [bin/wmic] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/wmic/wmi-1.3.16/Samba/source'
```

searched a bit for those functions and they seem to be obsolete and can be removed (as seen being done here https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/network/connman/connman.git/tree/gweb/giognutls.c?id=HEAD )

```
diff wmi-1.3.16_fixed/Samba/source/lib/tls/tls.c wmi-1.3.16/Samba/source/lib/tls/tls.c
507a508
>   gnutls_transport_set_lowat(tls->session, 0);
577a579
>   gnutls_certificate_type_set_priority(tls->session, cert_type_priority);
584a587
>   gnutls_transport_set_lowat(tls->session, 0);
```

can now compile and wmic appears to work fine